# Very simple expect script but does not work

Tags: expect

I've been trying to automatically decrypt encrypted Ansible yaml files. I know you can just set the ansible.cfg with

## vault_password_file = ~/.vault_pass.txt

But well, I was curious. Turns out I'm unable to do a simple task. Here is the dumb script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 9
set file [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ansible-vault decrypt $file
expect "Vault password:"
send "MyAwesomePassword\r"
```

Then I  use the script as

```
ansible-vault decrypt vars-mysql-config.yml
```

Output is

```
spawn ansible-vault decrypt /Users/ruben/ansible/vars/vars-mysql-config.yml
Vault password: %
```

No success. I know this is a stupid question but is so simple and I feel so stuck that I thought I forgot something.

Any ideas? thanks for reading!

Comment: Add `expect eof` at last after sending your password.

Comment: Hi @dinesh you were absolutely right! thanks a lot :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 9
set file [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ansible-vault decrypt $file
expect "Vault password: "
send "MyAwesomePassword\r" 
interact
```

I have added a space in expect command and added interact command in end.